# If $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ independent sets, then $\lim\sup \textbf{1}_{A_n}$ is constant

Tags: probability, independence, limsup-and-liminf

I want to prove that if $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ are independent sets, then the following functions are constant almost everywere:
$$\lim\sup \textbf{1}_{A_n} \quad \quad \lim\inf \textbf{1}_{A_n}$$
I don't know how to prove this. I don't know why does it matter the fact that $A_n$ are independent, since there are no probabilities here. I've tried using the fact that $w\in \lim \sup A_n \Longleftrightarrow w \in A_i$ for an infinite number if i's, and that $w\in \lim \inf A_n \Longleftrightarrow \exists n_0$ so that $w\in A_n \forall n\geq n_0$. That would mean that $\lim\sup \textbf{1}_{A_n}(x)=1 \Longleftrightarrow x \in A_i$ for an infinite number of i's, but it can be only for the even ones only (that is $x\in A_2, A_4, A_6,\ldots$) and that does't mean that the function is constant almost everywhere. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: Kołmogorov $0-1$ law (independence is needed here)

Comment: @DominikKutek can you be a bit more specific, please? How do I start?

Comment: $\mathcal G = \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \sigma( \bigcup_{n \ge N} 1_{A_n})$ is a tail $\sigma-$field and since all events are independent, random variables $1_{A_n}$ are independent, too, so in this sigma field, by Kołmogorov 0-1 law you have only events with probabality $0$ or $1$. Note that events of type $\{ \{\limsup_{n} 1_{A_n} \le t \} \in \mathcal G$ for any $t \in \mathbb R$. Hence the CDF of random variable $X = \limsup_{n} 1_{A_n}$ takes only $0$ or $1$ values. Can you show that $X$ must be constant?

Comment: @DominikKutek You wrote: $\bigcup_{n\geq N}1_{A_{n}}$. I don't understand that. $1_{A_{n}}$ are functions. How is the union of functions defined?

Comment: I've missed one $\sigma$ sign. It should be $\mathcal G = \bigcap_{N =1}^\infty \sigma( \bigcup_{n \ge N} \sigma(1_{A_n}) ) $